# Trying to stream an image to the browser from a url, need help putting tutorial into real world action

Tags: c#, webrequest

The main goal is to display an image from a url in the browser.  Obviously the image isn't available on a web server or I'd just use http://theurl....

I have found a two part 'tutorial' if you will, that does what I think will work for me.  I just can't figure out exactly how to get this to work.  It's missing things and I'm not sure what those things are.

I'm wondering if someone can put this into a complete codebehind page that I could use.

The first part shows how to Load an image from a url: http://www.vcskicks.com/image-from-url.php

And that page refers to this one, which shows how to get the file via an webrequest: http://www.vcskicks.com/download_file_http.php

Can someone help me put this together in a codebehind page, along with a page that actually calls this code and displays the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requirements for this have changed, and now need to display an entire html page, not just an image.  So I've opened a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

I belive this blog post is what you need.
http://www.codegolem.com/category/ASPNET.aspx?page=10

As it says there, the easiest way is to use a fake aspx page that returns the image as this other post do:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jrule/archive/2004/08/16/215393.aspx

Hope it helps

Comment: I can see, in theory, how this might work...but I would have no idea how to make this code work for an html page rather than an image...nor do if know if this is the best/only way to do it.  I would guess this isn't the only way to do it.